# Cannnot get joint torque while setting velocity command for joints

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I use following plugin for controlling joints.
https://github.com/start-jsk/rtmros_gazebo/blob/master/hrpsys_gazebo_general/src/IOBPlugin.cpp

I'm sending velocity command to joint by SetVelocity function, and trying to get joint torque by GetForce function, but return value of GetForce is always zero.

When I send torque command by SetForce function, I can get correct joint torque by GetForce.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6954/cannnot-get-joint-torque-while-setting-velocity-command-for-joints/) by [murooka](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/956/murooka/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-09-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IsaacS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/15/isaacs/) on 2015-01-15**:
Related question http://answers.ros.org/question/201068/gazebo-joints-getforce-returns-zero-when-used-in-conjunction-with-setmaxforce-and-setvelocity/

**Comment by [Daniel L](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/987/daniel-l/) on 2015-01-19**:
I posted the question referred above, but hasn't received a response yet. Has anyone found a way around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Can you try using [Joint::GetForceTorque](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/4.0.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Joint.html#a924807d32ef42bd741911ff33e7f3d53)?

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-01-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [murooka](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/956/murooka/) on 2015-06-22**:
Thank you. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

`SetVelocity` bypasses physics (see the call to [SetVelocityMaximal](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/e7aded6140484b7adccae3c612453deb798769f0/gazebo/physics/Joint.cc?at=default#cl-749) underneath), so forces were not computed based on target velocity.  To do this in a physically realistic fashion, write a force based PID controller that takes velocity target as feedback, and `GetForceTorque` should give you more physically meaningful readings.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2015-01-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel L](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/987/daniel-l/) on 2015-01-24**:
When I tested SetVelocity() with DefaultRobotSim, if you sent a command to a joint from Gazebo's Joints pane, non-zero force values would start being returned from there on for that particular joint, even if you stopped using the pane and started a ros_control controller. Why is this the case? My original question is here: http://answers.ros.org/question/201068/gazebo-joints-getforce-returns-zero-when-used-in-conjunction-with-setmaxforce-and-setvelocity/

**Comment by [murooka](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/956/murooka/) on 2015-06-22**:
GetForceTorque works well. Thank you!